# Find sequences where all elements have same sign and then change sign

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a series of lists with 7 elements (but could be any number). I am trying to find the lists that have all positive elements, all negative elements, and those that change sign at ANY point,

for example `[3, 6, 7, -2, -5, -1, -1]` or `[3, 1, -1, -2, -1, -5, -1]`.

Note that, though I used `integers` in my example, the `lists` are actually made of `floats`.

I can easily find all lists that are always positive or negative, but how do I find those that change sign (it could go from positive to negative as in example or from negative to positive).

Comment: What is the sign for 0 ? (np.sign (0) == 0)

Answer (score 1):

Use the for loop to iterate from 0th element to penultimate element and compare the signs or check if the product of 2 consecutive numbers is less than 0.

If yes, then append the elements in the list.

Comment: for loops are slow in python but your idea is good, I need to multiply consecutive elements and check if one and only one is negative. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assume the Series is

```py
0     [3, 6, 7, -2, -5, -1, -1]
1    [3, 1, -1, -2, -1, -5, -1]
dtype: object
```

You can try get the sign of each element of list in Series and sum them.

- If the result is 7, it means all positive,
- If the result is -7, it means all negative
- Otherwise, it may change the sign. (considering zero)

```py
m = s.apply(lambda lst: sum(map(np.sign, lst)))
```

```
print(m)

0   -1
1   -3
dtype: int64
```

To consider zero in list, you can join the sign list and check if there is `1,-1` or `-1,1`

```py
n = s.apply(lambda lst: ','.join(map(str, map(np.sign, lst))))
n = n.str.contains('1,-1|-1,1')
```

```
print(n)

0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

If you are not restrict with the 0 place, you can just check if there is `1` and `-1` in the sign list

```py
n = s.apply(lambda lst: {1, -1}.issubset(set(map(np.sign, lst))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be better implemented in numpy, has less overhead

```
x = np.array([[3, 6, 7, -2, -5, -1, -1],[3, 1, -1, -2, -1, -5, -1]])

allpositive = (x>0).all(axis=1)
allnegative = (x<0).all(axis=1)
mixed =  ((x>0)|(x<0)).any(axis=1)
```

Results for your particular dataset:

```
>>> x
array([[ 3,  6,  7, -2, -5, -1, -1],
       [ 3,  1, -1, -2, -1, -5, -1]])

>>> allpositive
array([False, False])
>>> allnegative
array([False, False])
>>> mixed
array([ True,  True])
```

Adapt the behavior to cover the sign of 0 to your taste.